# ear deployment in weblogic

Tags: deployment, weblogic, ear

I have an ear file containing 5 webapps. I want to use the same datasource in all the webapps.  Note this datasource will be created during the deployment of one of the webapps. For this reason, I want to give the sequence of deployment of webapps in my weblogic. I created application.xml in the sequence I want to deploy the webapps so that datasource is created when the first app is deployed and there after other apps can use it. However it seems the weblogic is not starting the app in the sequence as given in application.xml. Can anyone guide what more is required to specify the sequence of deployment of webapps in an ear?

Thanks

Comment: The Oracle docs claim all that should matter is the application.xml. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/deployment/concepts.html#1001981 What behavior are you seeing? Does one of your webapps come up and throw database errors?

Comment: Are you using PU's in your webapps?

Comment: PU means persistentUnit

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you configure On weblogic Server a Datasource and bind it in your 5 webapps?

Comment: you are right. that's one way to do. But there's a local env as well where we are using Jetty and therefore we need 2 implementation of datasources ?

Comment: Datasource settings are little differente from one server to another. If you are using differente Server so the datasource can not be the same

Comment: correct, thats what I meant. I was hoping if I create a datasource in a webapp in my ear . The datasource is spring bean . The same datasource can be shared with other webapps . But for some reason, that's not happening . Spring is creating datasource in all the apps.

Comment: No. not in the ear file. It will not work. The datasource config must be made on the weblogic server. You just need to make a reference on ddatasource in your war files#

Answer (score 0):

We can order the deployments in admin console while deploying the application...

Whenever you deploy any ear file...it will ask deployment order which is final one in that wizard and it's default value is 100.

you can specify the order like 100,101,102,103,104...or whatever number you want based on your requirement